# Getting an Int in another frame ActionScript 3.0

Tags: actionscript-3

I am currently working on a casino game (for my school) but I am encountering a problem:

```
var a:int //this part is in frame 1

a = 10000
money.text = ""+a //this part is working


//this part is in another frame
lost_BTN.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, lost)

function lost (e:MouseEvent)
{
cash.text = ""+a -=50 //*1 (please see below)
}
```

```
*1) Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 1', Frame 6, Line 36  1050: Cannot assign to a non-reference value.

*1) Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 1', Frame 6, Line 36  1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type String to an unrelated type Number.

*1) Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 1', Frame 6, Line 36  1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type Number to an unrelated type String.
```

I cant seem to get the information out of 'a' in another frame.

Comment: Casino game for school? Do you have to use sunglasses on exam?:)

Comment: I think this part is wrong: cash.text = ""+a -=50 maybe what you wanted is: cash.text = ""+ (a -50)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because your doing some calculation with `a` in frame 6 where you want to place the text. You should tell Flash that `a -= 50` should be interpreted as a `String` and you'll be good to go. If you change your code to this, it'll work:

```
function lost (e:MouseEvent)
{
    cash.text = String(a -=50);
}
```

Comment: Ah! that seems to work out. Thanks alot. I'll remember that one!

Answer (score 0):

As @rvmook mentions in his answer and @SeRPRo in the comment. Your error is about [operator precedence](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7fd1.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f6c). That is, the order in which operations are happening. In your example, the addition of the empty string and the value of `a` are happening before the intended subtraction-assignment of 50 from `a`. The result is that you are trying to subtract the integer `50` from a string containing the string representation of the value of `a`.

A slight re-work of your code will make it work fine, either with the string [cast](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f87.html) as @rvmook suggests or by performing the calculation first and then assigning the string representation.

```
function lost (e:MouseEvent)
{
    a -= 50;
    lost.text = a.toString();
}
```

Remember that computers are dumb and need t be told exactly what to do.

Comment: Oh! just out of curiosity; It is peforming the calculation while its in frame 1. Because I said it a:int? so it grabs that information. And it doesnt grab that information in the next frame(s)? As you can see I am quite new to this. But I am really exciting

Comment: No, by saying `a:int` you're declaring the variable in frame 1. You're then performing (or trying to perform) the calculation wherever you're doing `a -= 50`

Comment: I've updated the code a little to illustrate that the `-=` is done in the `lost` function

Comment: Okay! but now I am encountering another little problem. When I am going back to frame 1. My a value is set to 10000 again. I guess because of the a=10000. Anyway to fix this :p?

Comment: Don't go back to frame 1. Put your initialization stuff on frame 1 and have your main loop on frame 2. Eventually you'll realize better ways of building this kind of thing but this is good learning early on.

Comment: Alright, awesome. Thanks alot for the help.

I've seen some projects indeed and its all made in 1 frame. I was wondering why. But I think I just found me a reason. Thanks again.